# Sort strings in python based on date and time

Tags: python, sorting, datetime, timestamp

I have a list of strings in this format:

```
my_strings = [
"10.02.20 time 09.24",  
"06.02.20 time 08.51",  
"10.02.20 time 09.24",  
"10.02.20 time 09.25",  
"10.02.20 time 09.26",  
"10.02.20 time 09.27",  
"10.02.20 time 09.28",  
"10.02.20 time 09.29"   
]
```

How can I sort them based on date and time, both normally and reversely? I think I should use something like:

```
my_strings.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, "%d-%b-%y"))
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your format is "day.month.year time hour.minute", you need:

```
my_strings.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, '%d.%m.%y time %H.%M'))
```

If by "normally and reverse" you mean in ascending and descending order, for the latter you can either reverse the sorted list with `my_strings[::-1]`, or directly while sorting with `my_strings.sort(key=..., reverse=True)`.

Comment: Did you try both methods to see if they came out with the same order?  I suspect not.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - it actually does work, but only because the test data is poorly chosen.  Try changing the last item in `my_strings` to `"10.02.19 time 09.29"`.

Comment: @MarkRansom Ah, this is a very good point! I tunnel visioned because most dates were the same and didn't think about the logic. String sorting would have worked for year-month-day-hour-minute order only.

Comment: Yes, string sorting can work well - if the parts are in the correct order, and always have the same number of digits.  I'm a big believer in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) applied to UTC times.

Comment: @Reti43 your solution worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation for the [strptime function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#:%7E:text=timezone(timedelta(0)).-,strftime,-()%20and%20strptime()%20Behavior), the correct call for the function is:

```
strptime(date, "%d.%m.%y time %H.%M")
```

The `%b` you put in your code is for "Month as locale’s abbreviated names (Jan, Feb, …, Dec), but the correct is `%m` for "Month as a zero-padded decimal number", and you also need to include `time %H.%M` in the string declaring the format for it to work, or else you will get an `ValueError: time data '10.02.20 time 09.24' does not match format '%d.%b.%y'`

Comment: As for sorting, as @Reti43 said in its answer, a simple `my_strings.sort()` should work!

Comment: You can't sort by string unless the strings are in the proper format.  And these aren't.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score -1):

the statement you import into the datetime module may be `import datetime`, try `from datetime import datetime`.
it is all code

```
from datetime import datetime

my_strings = [
    "10.02.20 time 09.24",
    "06.02.20 time 08.51",
    "10.02.20 time 09.24",
    "10.02.20 time 09.25",
    "10.02.20 time 09.26",
    "10.02.20 time 09.27",
    "10.02.20 time 09.28",
    "10.02.20 time 09.29"
]
my_strings.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, "%y.%m.%d time %H.%M"))
print(my_strings)
```

Comment: Pay attention to the order of the date parts.